# why my controller post method request body returns undefined?

Tags: node.js, body-parser

I'm having a hard time achieving this post product method. I don't completely understand why I don't be able to get my request body since im new to this backend thing.

here's my full code I need your help to debug why I dont get my request body to my post request method controller.

**Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  ...
  });

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

**Controller**

```
const Product = require('../models/productModel');

...

const createProduct = (req, res) => {
  const {
    name,
    ...
  } = req.body;
  console.log(name);
  ...
};

module.exports = {
  ...
  createProduct,
  ...
};
```

Here in controller found out that the **console.log(name)** returns undefine and and I don't know why.

**Routes**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const productController = require('../controllers/productController');

...

// POST /api/products
router.post('/', productController.createProduct);

...

module.exports = router;
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// route imports
const productRoutes = require('./routes/productRoutes');

// local imports
const coonectDB = require('./db.js')

// Set up Express app
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// Set up body-parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Set up routes
app.use('/api/product', productRoutes);

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});

coonectDB()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('db connection succeeded.')
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

**Postman**
[Request Post using postman check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bORpC.png)

**VS Code Terminal**
[VS Code terminal logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMS41.png)

Thank you guys in advance and more power!

Comment: You most likely didn't send the body . How do you send the request?

Comment: i used postman API URL: `http://localhost:3000/api/product` | Method: `POST` | body using row {
    "name": "Example Product",
}

Comment: why people keeps downing my thread instead of helping :(

Comment: Try removing the `,` after `"Example Product"`

Comment: yes, I removed it but still undefined

Comment: @Konrad https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivKF0.png

Comment: @Konrad here's my vs code log screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMS41.png

Comment: Do you set the content type of the request to be `application/json` ?

Comment: hello, @GabrielePetrioli when can we possibly set that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the postman that the data you send is JSON and not text so that it sends the relevant request headers (*so that your app can decode it correctly*).

[image]

You should change the "Text" to "JSON"